# Plot a dataframe based on index values only

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple question. I have a dataframe with multiple columns for date and 2 index rows like this:

[image]

I wish to plot this given dataframe as a lineplot but based on indexes. What I mean by this is, I want a plot with 2 lines: Ptf and bmk representing the values in respective indices. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `data.T.plot()` is the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

With a DataFrame like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'2021-01-01': [0,1],
                            '2021-01-02': [2.3, 2.4],
                            '2021-01-03': [3.1, 4.2]},
                  index=['ptf', 'bmk'])
data.columns = pd.to_datetime(data.columns)
print (data)

     2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
ptf           0         2.3         3.1
bmk           1         2.4         4.2
```

You can access the transposed `data` with the `.T` property and then use the `.plot()` command. The `plot` method plots each column as a function of the index, so by transposing you get exactly what you are asking:

```py
data.T.plot()
```

[image]